# Suspicious network activity: sshd process showing up with lsof

Tags: security, sshd, lsof

I have a Raspberry Pi running Debian Jessie. I have pi-hole installed to block ad-serving domains (https://pi-hole.net). Going through the logs, I noticed a lot of queries from a Chinese domain.

`lsof -i` shows me the following list that I feel is suspected:

```
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd  1742  root  3u  IPv4  16960  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->116.31.116.47:50600 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1743  sshd  3u  IPv4  16960  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->116.31.116.47:50600 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1774  root  3u  IPv4  16990  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->183.214.141.105:56265 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1775  sshd  3u  IPv4  16990  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->183.214.141.105:56265 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1869  root  3u  IPv4  17068  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->116.31.116.47:33525 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1870  sshd  3u  IPv4  17068  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->116.31.116.47:33525 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1910  root  3u  IPv4  17122  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->116.31.116.47:35816 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1911  sshd  3u  IPv4  17122  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->116.31.116.47:35816 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1931  root  3u  IPv4  17158  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->116.31.116.47:49492 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1932  sshd  3u  IPv4  17158  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->116.31.116.47:49492 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1935  root  3u  IPv4  17163  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->183.214.141.105:23828 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1936  sshd  3u  IPv4  17163  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->183.214.141.105:23828 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1937  root  3u  IPv4  17168  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->116.31.116.47:53628 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1938  sshd  3u  IPv4  17168  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->116.31.116.47:53628 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1940  root  3u  IPv4  17176  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->116.31.116.47:57858 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1941  sshd  3u  IPv4  17176  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->116.31.116.47:57858 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1944  root  3u  IPv4  17194  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->183.214.141.105:28355 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd  1945  sshd  3u  IPv4  17194  0t0  TCP raspberrypi:ssh->183.214.141.105:28355 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I already changed my password, restarted my Pi and checked for any unknown users (which there were none). How do I proceed making my Pi secure again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There may or may not be a security breach.

It may just be an idiot trying to brute force crack passwords. If they connect, try a password, it fails, they don't try another or close the connection then you can see these connections which will eventually be closed by the sshd.

```
/var/log/auth.log
```

should have some information on the login attempts. the `last` command may show you successful logins.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. Indeed it looked like a brute force attack. One of the first things I have done now is install fail2ban (http://iot-projects.com/index.php?id=make-your-raspberry-pi-more-secure). I'll furthermore consider single packet authorization and blocking incoming Chinese and Russian IP addresses at my router.

Comment: You might find sites like http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/ helpful.

Comment: I do not got that file on arch nor fedora

Comment: @nixda what additional information are you looking for

Comment: Fail2ban is helpful, and will slow down the attacks, but even better would be to scrape the fail2ban logs and permanently firewall the offending subnets.  Or just close ssh to outside access entirely and only whitelist subnets you care about.  Or set up port knocking.

Answer (score 1):

As icarus already mention, it is not possible to know for sure if there was a security breach on your server. If `lsof -i` or `ss -tulpn` show an established connection *from* your host (from ssh/22 port) to a suspicious IP, you might consider starting from scratch.

`last` is useful to see successful logins, but you might be interested on `lastb`

```bash
sudo lastb  # Show a list of all last logged in users
sudo lastb --since YYYY-MM-DD  # Show a list of all last logged in users since a given time
```

Some security advices I didn't see on the other answers:

- Move sshd listening port from 22 to a higher random TCP port. Change `Port 22` on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Could also add port-knocking.
- `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` (idem `without-password`) on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to avoid anyone to login through ssh with root user.
- Before restarting sshd service use [test mode, `sudo sshd -T`](https://superuser.com/a/1291078/500826).
- Try tools like `fail2ban` y `psad`
- Use a firewall, like `ufw`.
- Keep your things updated.
- Related articles

  - https://www.ssh-audit.com/hardening_guides.html
  - https://seinecle.github.io/linux-security-tutorials/generated-html/step-by-step-guide-en.html

Answer (score 0):

To make your raspberrypi secure you should disable password login on ssh server. Only use public key authentication (this can't be brute forced).

for that first copy your ssh public key your pi.

Then under `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d` put `securepi.conf`
which should have these lines:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

and restart ssh server.

I don't like to directly edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` because changes are hard to track and reverse but in case of a file under `sshd_config.d` you just have to delete the file to reverse the changes.

Two more suggestions:

1. Use cloudflare tunnels instead of opening a port, It will prevent DDOS and similar attacks.
2. Only allow connection from specific IPs using firewall rules.

Comment: While this is a good idea, it won't stop the brute force login attempts.  Just having the port open will attract brute force attacks that use up your bandwidth.

Comment: brute forcing public key authentication is impractical, just imagine time and computing power required.

Comment: Brute force attacks are guaranteed if your port is open and not firewalled.  *successful* brute force attacks are impractical.   Think DoS attack, not access attack..